# Is automatically assigning focus bad for accessibility?

Tags: javascript, accessibility, dhtml

If I have a form that is the main part of a page's content, will assigning focus to the first form field via JavaScript on page load have any negative effects on accessibility?

Comment: See also http://ui.stackexchange.com/questions/2861/drawbacks-of-auto-focusing-on-a-web-pages-text-field-javascript

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The short answer is no it doesn't make things inaccessible but it can make it confusing. The longer answer follows. Will your users know that there going to a page with a form, and does there need to be any descriptive text you should read before filling out the form? I'm a screen reader user and it can be annoying having focused put in random fields. It's clear why your focus winds up in the Google search box so that doesn't bother me. If my focus were automatically placed in the answer edit field every time I viewed a question on Stackoverflow I would be annoyed since I'd have to force my screen reader to navigate away from the form field and to the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks Jared.  This is a good answer. I'd like to get closer to some consensus in the community though.

We're struggling with this here for Drupal 8 - https://drupal.org/node/2096347

There are other links here:

https://dequeuniversity.com/assets/html/jquery-summit/html5/slides/form-attributes.html

Comment: Also worth adding:

http://webaim.org/blog/future-web-accessibility-html5-input-extensions/

So, using HTML5's autofocus is better than using javascript or tabindex because it can be disabled by the user agent.  However, it has to be carefully considered before use.

Comment: It is likely more accessible to use HTML5 autofocus attribute if that is an option http://webaim.org/blog/future-web-accessibility-html5-input-extensions/

Comment: Agree with the answer by all further examples given, but not with stating 'no' in first place. The short answer for most websites would be 'possibly yes' in my humble opinion. 
Risking to let an assistive technology user loose orientation by ending them up in the middle of a page? Orientation is one of the key elements for good information architecture, putting a dent into it should be avoided at most.

Answer (score 2):

It might a bit, if we've got a keyboard user (either using a screen-reader, or just a habitual keyboard user) who's expecting to be navigating the links at the top of the page on first Tab press. For screen readers, you could also consider adding WAI-ARIA to add directions if users who don't expect to be dumped into the middle of a form.

If it's much more likely that the user's going to be wanting to type in the field straight away, then I think the autofocus is worth it. But for the reason above I wouldn't use it on *every* page with an input field.

If you do autofocus, make sure to do it right away, in a script as soon as possible following the input element, or in future using the HTML5 autofocus attribute. Don't do it as late as `window.onload`. It's annoying to have clicked the focus elsewhere only to have the document belatedly finish loading and steal the focus onto another element as you type.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of sites will do this, google is a good example, the only issue is when you are typing something into the address bar, or into the search input in your browser, the action of focusing the form field tends to steal focus from where you are typing.  It's a small nuisance.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [MDN autofocus -> accessibility considerations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autofocus#accessibility_considerations) (retrieved 9/28/2022):

> Automatically focusing a form control can confuse visually-impaired people using screen-reading technology and people with cognitive impairments. When `autofocus` is assigned, screen-readers "teleport" their user to the form control without warning them beforehand.
>
> Use careful consideration for accessibility when applying the `autofocus` attribute. Automatically focusing on a control can cause the page to scroll on load. The focus can also cause dynamic keyboards to display on some touch devices. While a screen reader will announce the label of the form control receiving focus, the screen reader will not announce anything before the label, and the sighted user on a small device will equally miss the context created by the preceding content.

To add some practical examples, at the time of writing, https://www.google.com autofocuses on the search box, while Wikipedia and Amazon don't. If typing into a search box is the sole purpose of the page and the risk of confusion is low, then it's worth considering autofocusing on it. Otherwise, probably skip autofocusing.

Answer (score -1):

> will assigning focus to the first form field via JavaScript on page load have any negative effects on accessibility?

I can't think of any. In between fields might irritate whatever assistive software a user might be running, but the first field - hardly. I have no experience with braille and similar clients.

Seeing as even Google do it on their front page, I don't think it can be that big a deal either way.

Comment: Just because someone uses a screen reader doesn't mean they don't use JavaScript. The page is rendered in the browser complete with JavaScript, then a model of the page is handed off to the screen reader. When the page is updated with JavaScript those updates are sent to the model of the page the screen reader works with.

Answer (score -3):

I wouldn't say so, fragments are an ingredient of HTTP and they set the focus of an *html page..

Comment: Come again - what "fragments"?

Comment: fragments = #TextAtTheEndOfAURL

Answer (score -4):

I wouldn't say so. A screenreader will probably not even notice this since it doesn't interpret the JavaScript on the page.

Another user which has a "normal" browser will get the advantage of having the cursor already at the right place which facilitates the navigation by using just the keyboard.

Comment: As a screen reader user this is not correct. The browser runs the JavaScript then returns a model of the page to the screen reader. This means you can easily be placed in a form field with no context of what it is or why your there.

Comment: Very interesting! - Just goes to show what a useful community this is. I've been a web developer for about 12 years or so and I would have given exactly the same answer as Juri. I had no idea that screen readers worked in this way now days. I will be having a fresh look at accessibility in the near future. Can you detect a screen reader and perhaps focus a different, more useful part of the page instead?

Comment: There's no way to detect weather a screen reader is running from with in a browser that i know of. If you want to have a look at ways to help screen reader users by providing extra information take a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-wai-aria-20080204/ Not sure if this is the newest version but it is the version linked to when Google announced they had put ARIA support into Google reader.

Comment: Interesting. Thx @Jared. Didn't know that actually. I though screen readers just interpret the HTML and completely ignore JavaScript.

Comment: I wanted to add a related question to this thread:

http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60026/when-is-it-appropriate-to-add-the-html5-autofocus-attribute-to-a-page

@jared do you have any current stats on how well HTML5's autofocus is supported by screen readers? Can screen readers be set to ignore this attribute these days? The WebAim article is a bit out of date now.